# convert pcolormesh plot in python to .mat file

Tags: python, matlab

I created a script in python and use pcolormesh to plot an intensity graph. I want to save the data in that plot with specific resolution in .mat file to be used by another software.

Comment: Add some succinct example code.  This will help people to help you.

Comment: my code is available here

https://github.com/surajmehta/modesolver.git

Comment: A .mat file is a data file, not an image file.  I am not clear what you mean by saving a figure to a data file.